# Microsoft Sculpt Mouse connection issue

Tags: bluez

I recently updated to 18.04 and now I have problems with a mouse that I used before without any issues. I already tried updating my bluez Version to 5.50 but that didn't help. After the PC went to sleep or even if I just don't use the mouse for some time but the PC is running, the mouse wont work anymore. The bluetooth console shows that the device is reconnecting all the time:

```
[CHG] Device F0:1D:BC:E7:22:79 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device F0:1D:BC:E7:22:79 Connected: no
[CHG] Device F0:1D:BC:E7:22:79 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device F0:1D:BC:E7:22:79 Connected: no
[CHG] Device F0:1D:BC:E7:22:79 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device F0:1D:BC:E7:22:79 Connected: no
[CHG] Device F0:1D:BC:E7:22:79 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device F0:1D:BC:E7:22:79 Connected: no
```

and so on...

To reconnect I have to go into pairing mode on the mouse again.

any ideas how to fix that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with a Logitech M535 under 18.04. Pairing it differently, via terminal, is what resolved it for me:

- Unpair everything
- Set the mouse to discoverable
- run `bluetoothctl` (list the MAC address of your mouse, a number like 00:1F:28:FE:04:82)
- run `pair <MAC>` (within bluetoothctl which paired the device)

You might also want to trust the device with

```
trust <MAC>
```

When done, just type `quit`

Restart your computer, your mouse should now connect automatically after sleep or restart.